# Can you set the title and meta description via Dreamweaver's news.json?

Tags: meta-tags, dreamweaver

For some reason or another, a website I started managing is running on Dreamweaver and to update the posts and feed, I have to edit a news.json file.

The problem is that these are only set fields in here, and the meta title and meta description all populate to be the same.

```
"ID": "20190814-01",
"title": " Post Titles",
"date": "(August 14, 2019) — ",
"shortDesc": "Description of post/excerpt for posts landing page",
"fullStory": "Full content of post",
"displayDate": "Article was posted on August 14, 2019."
```

Since I am not familiar with this format, is it possible to find and enter fields like `"metaTitle"`, `"metaDescription"`?

Would there be other files I would need to modify to get these to show?

Comment: The `<title>` tag is not a meta tag.   There is no such thing as a "meta title".   One it doesn't use `<meta>` and two, it is shown to users in the window decoration and tabs.   You should refer to it as just the "title", or the "page title".

Comment: Yep, you're absolutely correct. I'm used to talking to non-tech so "meta tag" is commonly thrown around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around in the site's php files I found a feed that seems to bridge the files:

```
   $urlID = substr($urlString, $eqPos + 1, 11);  

   switch ($urlID) { 
   case "20190823-01"; /*ID from other php file listed above */
   $title = "Sample title";
   $metaDescription = "Sample description.";
   break;
```

And this feeds through each post but is not dynamically generated.
Appreciate the question views and hope this may help someone in the future.